# 2 complex representations have the same character iff they are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I have to prove the following statement:

> Let $\rho: G \to GL(V),  \tau: G \to GL(W)$ be representations of a
>   finite group $G$. Then $\rho$ and $\tau$ are equivalent if and only if
>   $\chi_\rho = \chi_\tau$

I can use the following theorems, and nothing else:

> If $(.|.): \mathbb{C}^G\times \mathbb{C}^G \to \mathbb{C}^G:
>  (\phi|\psi) \mapsto \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}
>  \phi(g)\overline{\psi(g)}$, then we have:
>
> If $\chi$ is a complex, irreducible character of a finite group $G$,
>   then $(\chi|\chi) = 1$
>
> If $\chi_\rho, \chi_\tau$ are irreducible, complex characters and
>   $\rho$ not equivalent to $\tau$, then $(\chi_\rho|\chi_\tau) = 0$

---

> If $\rho =  \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \rho_i $, and $\chi_\rho'$ is an
>   irreducible character of a certain representation $\tau$, then the
>   amount of irreducible components in the direct sum decomposition (as
>   written above) equivalent with $\rho'$, is given by
>   $(\chi_\rho|\chi_\rho')$

My attempt:

$\boxed{\Rightarrow}$ Let $\rho$ and $\tau$ be equivalent representations, then for $g \in G$ and for a certain isomorphism $f: V \to W$ we have

$$\rho_g = f \circ \tau_g \circ f^{-1}$$

and $Tr(\rho_g) = Tr([f \circ \tau_g \circ f^{-1}]) = Tr(\tau_g)$ by the cyclic property of trace. Hence, $\chi_\rho = \chi_\tau$

$\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ Here I'm stuck. Can someone hint me in the right direction here? I tried to use the second theorem I listed, but could not find a correct argument.

Comment: Since the characters are equal, the inner product with a fixed irreducible character is the same for both representations.  Thus, by the second quoted theorem, the number of factors isomorphic to a fixed irreducible component is the same.  Since this holds for *any* fixed irreducible, then the representations are the same (since they are both sums of irreducible components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\langle \phi, \psi \rangle := \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}
 \phi(g)\overline{\psi(g)}$$

is an inner product on the vector space $\mathbb{C}^G$ and then, according to the second theorem, the characters of non-isomorphic irreducible representations are linearly independent.

Now, let $V_1, ..., V_k$ be an isomorphy list of all simple $G$-modules. Assume that $M = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k m_i V_i,  W = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k w_i V_i$ (where the $m_i$'s and the $w_i$'s are the multiplicities, meaning $m_i V_i = V_i \oplus ... \oplus V_i$, $m_i$ times of addition) have the same characters. Moreover, the third theorem yields:

$$\chi_M = \sum_{i=1}^k m_i \cdot \chi_{V_i} = \sum_{i=1}^k w_i \cdot \chi_{W_i} = \chi_W.$$

Owing to the linear independence, we deduce $m_i = w_i$ for all $i$ and hence $M \simeq W$.